# Why isn't my link attribute getting my css?

Tags: php, pages, css, page-template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

That is the line I am using.
The `style.css` file is in the same directory as the file I am running that from.
Tt specifically just won’t work on my wordpress page.
I am running the page via a HTML file that I am using as the template for that page.
It IS getting that file because it does display the HTML elements.
Just wont style them with my stylesheet. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Just Copy and Paste above code.